# Why after calling ondestroy of my Activity i am still seeing Toasts from that same Activity which is destroyed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an android app in which first when the user opens my app I show the `Splashscreen` and after that user is navigated to `HomeActivity`.

Now actually I saw a strange thing happening which is before `ondestroy()` function of my `Splashscreen` I am calling a function which is calling a `Toast` and making `progressBar GONE` but the thing is, I mistakenly called this function in a loop so what is happening is my Splashscreen ondestroy function got called, my HomeActivity is showing but still Toasts are being shown from Splashscreen again and again.

Now my question is as after destroying the Splashscreen why android is not giving me the error because as I am referencing `Toast and ProgressBar` which is bound to the Splashscreen so it must give me the error.

And also if it should not give me the error then please tell me what is the concept which is working here and I don't know. **Isn't all variables which we make in our activity class gets bound only to that activity and when that activity gets destroyed so does them** ??

My **Splashscreen function code** is given below which is getting called again and again

```
public void function showdialog() {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Total Pending Notifications: " + pen_notifs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the source code and this is my theory.

`Toast` internally uses `Service` (Notification service) to queue and show the `Toast` views. `Service` runs in background and its lifecycle outlives any `Activity`'s.

The `Notification Service` has a reference to the `Toast` view that you are created using the `makeText()` method.

And the `Toast` view has an implicit reference to the `context` which is your `Activity`'s `context`.

So since the `Notification service` has a reference to your `Toast` view and the `toast` view has a reference to your `Activity`, your `Activity` hasn't been destroyed at all. Your `Activity` is leaking. Since your `Activity` hasn't been destroyed, you are not getting any `NullPointerException`s even if the `progressBar` is accessed after the `onDestroy()` callback.

The for loop has been running continuously and the `Notification service` implicitly holds a reference to your `Activity`. So there is no chance for your `Activity` to get destroyed.

Comment: Biut my onDestory() function gets called ??

Comment: Yes your `onDestroy` will get called when the `Activity` is supposed to be destroyed. But if any other living entity (`Service` in your case) holds a strong reference to your `Activity`, that `Activity` cannot be Garbage collected. That is called Activity leak.

Comment: You can use any tool (like Leakcanary: https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect if your Activity is leaking. i.e. still living even after `onDestroy` has been called.

Answer (score 1):

The toast works over all parts of the app.
In your code you do not initialize the variable which stores the toast inside.

What about the solution.

I would suggest to use something like this:

```
private Toast toast;

private void function cancel() {
      if (toast != null)
            toast.cancel();
}
private void function showdialog() {
      toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Total Pending Notifications: " + pen_notifs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      toast.show();
      progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Then why when i am calling `progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` i am not getting any error ??

Comment: visibility state is just a boolean variable. it is used only while rendering the screen. This is the separate loop. If `progressbar` is not `null` no error will be exist.

Comment: Ok i even tried to call Localbroadcast from there ?? Don't you think when activity is destroyed then we should not be able to call any method of that activity ??

Comment: Of course, this is highly unrecommented due to lots of dependcies are removed after destroying.